# Dell M620 Windows 2012R2 Boot from iSCSI to PS6000 Issue

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, iscsi, dell-poweredge

All QLogic drivers are current.  The iSCSI initiator connects to the target and volume (of course there is no OS yet) when testing the boot.  I've read the Dell Configuring Windows Server 2012 for iSCSI SAN Boot with EqualLogic Storage.  When I get to the storage dialog during Windows setup there is no device.  How can I get the remote storage to display?

Comment: Is the volume ACL (on the PS6000 side) set correctly ?

Comment: There is no access control, for the sake of simplicity.  I can test the settings during boot, see that it gets the IP from DHCP and then tries to logon to the target.  It shows success in logging in to the target.  Unless Windows requires access control in order to connect, but it seems like it would just use the network card's own settings.  I'd love to see a log file for whether Windows is actually even making an effort to use the NIC's settings to logon and if it is failing why.